# Laravel Page Route Not Using The Correct Parameters Passed In

Tags: laravel, web, routes, laravel-livewire

Hey all you smart people,

Im having a issue I normally work with API routes not really used Web Routes before and finding this rather complicated for some reason :D

Ive made this route

```
Route::get('/test/{page?}', \App\Http\Livewire\Test::class);
```

sand this is my logic in the render() in the controller

```
public function render(Request $request, $page = 1)
{
    dd($page);
}
```

however when I'm on the browser and type

```
http://url.com/test/2
```

The Die Dump keeps giving me page 1 all the time am i missing something here ??

Thanks for the help if anyone can help...

**Update**

Im not sure if its because I'm using a livewire component and not an actual controller....

Livewire Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Livewire\Component;

class Test extends Component
{
    public function render(Request $request, $page = 1)
    {
        dd($page);
        return view('livewire.test');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route Parameters in `livewire` works like this

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/test/{page?}', \App\Http\Livewire\Test::class);
```

**component**

```php
public function mount($page = 1)
{
    dd($page);
}
```

ref link https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#route-params

Comment: always look in official doc